# How to keep double quotes in a bash execution inside sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, xml

I have a log file containning a lot of line like this:

```
2021/09/03-13:11:05;QUEUE.INBOUND;4;ID:myhost.mydomain.net-7756-1629822315072-199:973:1:1:1;MISC;"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <RootElement xmlns="urn:namespace:entity/1" tstamp="2021-02-29T12:11:00Z" object="urn:domain:entity:ID1234"><Active lang="en" value="true">active</Active><Name lang="en">Some Name</Name><ShortName lang="en">shortname</ShortName><Phone number="+416458838829" lang="en">+416458838829</Phone><Email>info@somewhere.com</Email><Longitude>7.043786</Longitude><Latitude>47.239036</Latitude></RootElement>"
```

(The XML is larger than this but this is just an example.)

My goal is to extract each XML from each line to a dedicated file. If the log contains 10 lines, hence 10 files would be created.

I started with this:

```
more mylogfile.txt | sed -r 's!^.*\s(<RootElement.*\sobject="urn:domain:entity:([A-z0-9]*)"><Active.*</RootElement>).*!echo "\1" | xmlstarlet fo > "\2.xml"!e; d'
```

The idea is to extract the ID in the object urn and use it for the file name (id's are unique in the file).

Issue:

when doing the "echo" command alone

```
more mylogfile.txt | sed -r 's!^.*\s(<RootElement.*\sobject="urn:domain:entity:([A-z0-9]*)"><Active.*</RootElement>).*!echo "\1"!e; d'
```

I noticed the double quote inside the XML are just wiped and the `xmlstarlet` command (in the first try) will just make an error.

Example of the Active element will become:

```
<Active lang=en value=true>active</Active>
```

I know there are some trick with the syntax when executing a bash command in `sed` and `echo`, but I tried several different syntax (like removing the "" around \1, using `printf`, using `xargs` outside `sed` instead, etc...) but none of them are successful.

I am using a Ubuntu distro 18.04 (WSL 1 under windows).

Is there any option in `echo` or "`sed` `s!...!...!e`" command to improve this?

(If you find a more efficient way, I am open too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes first with `s/"/\\"/g`. This will keep them from being eaten by `echo`.

Then remember to adapt you search pattern. You need to match `\"` instead of `"`, and the backslash needs to be escaped, so it needs to be `\\"` in the search pattern:

```
sed -E 's/"/\\"/g;s!^.*\s(<RootElement.*\sobject=\\"urn:domain:entity:([A-Za-z0-9]*)\\"><Active.*</RootElement>).*!echo "\1"!e;d'
```

Comment: mmm I did not think about escaping the " before processing -> it works perfectly, thanks for your answer (accepted).  I think the "foo" expression is useless in your echo command right?

Comment: @рüффп Oops, yes, of course. Removed it.